# ¿Cómo se llama este animal?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, animales, identificación-de-término

¿Cómo se llama este animal en la foto en español?

Me and my friend we are debating on how it's called.

[image]

Comment: do you know the name in english ?

Comment: I didn't want to suggest / influence anybody with our option that's why I just posted the picture. It's a "Steinbock" / Capricorn. In German and in Italian we use it for the animal and as well for the zoidiac sign. I was the option that also in Spanish you can use it for both, while my friend said that it doesn't work for the "animal". Like the answer from pablodf76 she also came up with "Capra salvaje". @walen

Comment: Just to note, *capra* is Italian or Latin for goat. The Spanish word is _ca**b**ra_. Some Spanish words related to goats still retain the *p* though: *caprario, capricornio, capricorniano* etc

Comment: ¿Y como se llama en inglés? "capricorn" is not right in English. It's an ibex in English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buscando en Google la foto, los resultados relevantes están en alemán y dicen que el animal es un *[Steinbock](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinbock)* (nombre genérico de varias especies del género *Capra*) y que fue fotografiado en los [Prealpes appenzelleses](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prealpes_appenzelleses), más precisamente en el macizo de Alpstein. Con esa localización y comparando con otras fotos, parece claro que es un ejemplar de *[Capra ibex](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capra_ibex)*, un **íbice alpino** o **cabra salvaje de los Alpes**.

[image: Capra ibex]

El nombre común de los animales del género *Capra*, en castellano, es *cabra* (femenino). Viene del latín *capra*, con un cambio fonético regular /p/ > /b/ que no se produjo en italiano (al menos al sur de la [Línea La Spezia-Rimini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Spezia%E2%80%93Rimini_Line)). En castellano existen algunas palabras cultas latinas que conservan la /p/, como *caprino* ("relativo a las cabras, *ganado caprino*"). La forma masculina es *cabrón*, pero esa palabra es malsonante en muchos dialectos, así que en cambio se utiliza más *macho cabrío*. En otras regiones es más común llamar al animal *chivo* (m.) / *chiva* (f.).

*Cabra* es el nombre habitual para ciertas especies (tanto salvajes como domesticadas) del género, pero *Capra ibex* en particular se llama *íbice* (m.). Esta palabra no es tan común ni conocida como *cabra*.

En castellano los nombres de los signos zodiacales no son palabras castellanas, sino palabras latinas apenas modificadas: *Aries, Tauro, Géminis, Cáncer, Leo, Virgo, Libra, Escorpio, Sagitario, Capricornio, Acuario, Piscis*. Algunos son parecidos a nombres de animales (*Leo ~ león, Escorpio ~ escorpión, Tauro ~ toro*), pero ninguno es idéntico.

Comment: También se conoce como el ***íbice alpino*** [ [1](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capra_pyrenaica) [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ordte8jhi4M) [3](http://wikifaunia.com/mamiferos/ibice/) [4](http://eprints.ucm.es/34591/) ] a diferencia del [*íbice* ***ibérico*** *(/ cabra montés)*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capra_pyrenaica) y la [***cabra*** *alpina*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capra_aegagrus_hircus#Razas).

Comment: @tjfuke capricorn (same as the zodiacal sign) would be wrong for the "animal" ? thanks

Comment: *Capricorn* isn't a Spanish word. The constellation/star-sign in Spanish is called *Capricornio*. A person who has that star-sign is called [a] *capricornio*. **Capricorni** is a (zoological) word in Spanish but refers specifically to *serows* - goat-like mammals, closely related to goats and sheep, found in central/eastern Asia. Goats in general in Spanish are called *cabras*. You could call this animal *una cabra*, but to distinguish it from domesticated goats (*cabra/chiva*) you would need to use one of the more specific terms above: ***íbice / íbice alpino / cabra salvaje de los Alpes***.

Comment: @gsharp *Capricorn* is from Latin, *capri-* means "goat" and *corn-* refers to horns (the English word *horn* is related to the Latin *cornū* and to Spanish *cuerno*). You wouldn't call this animal *capricornio* but the standard representation of Capricorn in the zodiac is a horned goat, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @pablo would you mind adding a warning and explanation why we say *cabra* (feminine).  I think that would strengthen your answer and would be doing a civic service for OP and future readers.

Comment: @aparente001 What do you mean, why we say *cabra*? Ah, never mind, just saw the latest comments on the question.

Comment: @pablodf76 - Bingo, nice explanation.  I've even heard "cabrita" to get even more distance from the masculine!

Answer (score 1):

Por el aspecto parece un [**muflón**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovis_orientalis_musimon). Compara tu imagen con las de [**aquí**](https://duckduckgo.com/?&q=mufl%C3%B3n&iax=images&ia=images).

Comment: El muflón parece tener los cuernos en espiral mientras este no. Según http://www.vertebradosibericos.org/mamiferos/oviori.html el muflón es de la familia de las ovejas y el de la pregunta es de la familia de las cabras. Igual si se parecen :-) gracias a este comentario conocí el muflón.